# ERROR: Invalid argument error in windows CMD

Tags: windows, command-line

i am trying to run the following code line and i am getting errors. i try to get the files that is over 1gb and older than 7.

C:\Windows\system32>for %i in (.tmp, .mdmp ,.trc ,.log) do forfiles -p "O:\" -s -m *%i -d -7 -c "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 124288000 echo @path @fdate"

C:\Windows\system32>forfiles -p "O:\" -s -m *.tmp -d -7 -c "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 124288000 echo @path @fdate"
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@fsize'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.

Comment: Please help. why am i getting this one wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove double quotes from -p "O:\".

```
for %i in (.tmp, .mdmp ,.trc ,.log) do forfiles -p O:\ -s -m *%i -d -7 -c "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 124288000 echo @path @fdate"
```